# How to create a schema for mysql in express and is it needed?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and I'm currently learning nodejs, expressjs, reactjs and mysql stack. I have found tutorials about this stack but the tutorials only cover mongodb for the database. I am already connected to a mysql database. My question is do I need to create a schema for it, and if so, how do I create the schema?

Comment: If by _"schema"_ you mean a database and tables, then yes

Comment: I am already connected to a local database. Is there still a need in creating a schema, and if so how to do it?

Comment: Before we go any further, what do _you_ mean by _"schema"_?

Comment: The database, tables, datatypes and etc.

Comment: What are you going to query if you don't have any tables?

Comment: I already created tables in mysqlworkbench

Comment: So you already have a database and tables (aka a _"schema"_). What exactly is your question then?

Comment: Do I also create one in my directory or is this unecessary?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. We've already established what a [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) is so what do you mean by _"create one in my directory"_? One _what_?

Comment: Sorry if what I am saying is unclear, as I said I am new. So nvm this question. I'd like to ask instead what is the mysql equivalent of mongoose.

Comment: The poster clearly means to ask if they can/should create a description of the schema in the express app. This is possible with MongoDB using mongoose and makes it easier to write queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have a connection to your mysql server, now you need a schema other than your sys schema in order to model custom database. Do not use sys db as this for the server itself.

To create a schema simply use MySql Workbench and create one (there is at least a button in the top navigation, one in the Menu Bar, and also "should" be one when right-clicking on the root element on the left). You define a name and then navigate into the schema from there you select tables and create a table as you like.

Comment: I already have sample tables.

Comment: The Question itself is not very clear. Thus the answer is not helpfull.

Comment: The Question is clear to me, that is why I provided an answer. Assuming that an answer is not helpful because the question was not clear, is not helpful either.